# Plone theme based on default using Diazo

Tags: plone, diazo

In Plone 4, I would like to create a new theme using Diazo that is based on the default Plone theme.  But when I go to control panel and create a new Diazo theme, it basically clears everything and gives me a blank slate.

How do I start with the basic/default theme for Plone 4 and modify that?

Answer (score 1):

Install [plonetheme.diazo_sunburst](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plonetheme.diazo_sunburst) first, then modify it instead of the new Diazo theme.